# Trying to put a ListView.builder inside a Column with other childrens

Tags: flutter

I get this error when try to make this composition of Column and ListView.builder

> ======== Exception caught by rendering library ===================================================== RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderSingleChildViewport#1fb04 relayoutBoundary=up10
> NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1930
> pos 12: 'hasSize'

How to fix it?

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  body: SingleChildScrollView( // The relevant error-causing widget
    child: Column(
      children: [
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [...],
              ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 100,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {...},
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 3):

remove the `Expanded` widget and assign `shrinkWrap` property of `Listview.builder` to true

```js
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  body: SingleChildScrollView( // The relevant error-causing widget
    child: Column(
      children: [
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [...],
              ),
          ),
          ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 100,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {...},
          ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try to remove Expanded Widget on just above the List view Builder

Answer (score 0):

Add the `listview` inside a `sizedbox` widget and set height to the sizedbox widget

Answer (score 0):

problem :  List view inflate as can take all space and u put it in Expanded widget inside column so you give  infinity space to it .
salutation : just wrap this Expanded widget to container , Give fixed height and width for this container and it will work.